# Composition of defined functions (that are $\Delta_0$) is not $\Delta_0$

Tags: set-theory

I am interested in an example for the above. I am not asking for the composition to not be equivalent to a $\Delta_0$ formula (which holds see for Kunen's set Theory p.147 exercise 13), but much weaker there should be an example where pure syntactically we dont get a $\Delta_0$ formula by composition.

Definition:
A defined Function $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a formula $\Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)$ such that
$$\forall x_1,\ldots,x_n:\exists!y: \Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)$$ holds in say ZF.

We say $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=y$ is abbreviating $\Phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n,y)$.

$\Delta_0$ formulas are those formulas of LST, where each quantifier is bounded.

So i want $\Delta_0$-defined-functions F,G such that $z=F(G(x))$ is not $\Delta_0$.

Of course the example from Kunen which isn't equivalent will also not be $\Delta_0$. But i wasn't able to construct the Formulas for the functions im supposed to.